# There should be a sign that someone's editing a question/answer.

Tags: feature-request, editing

It may easily happen that you're editing a hugely improperly written question/answer and it so happens that someone else is editing too, and after you're all done it turns out you've been wasting your time.

Why don't we create a sign that would signify that someone else is editing a question/answer?

Comment: This might have the bad effect of making *both* editors drop the edit, much like when two people let the other pass in the cross-section, and no-one passes.

Answer (score 4):

How would the system know somebody (else) is editing?

It could go on the click of "edit" but then perhaps somebody just hit the button an then decided to let it be. The system could further monitor the users activity, but all this is a bit cumbersome.

There is however a  notification for the case the question was actually edited while one is editing.

Comment: Sidenote: Quora has fully implemented this, but in answering instead of editing: you're shown who is currently writing an answer (you're marked as writing it if there's at least one symbol you've already written).